# Which iPhones support the apt-X codec for Bluetooth audio?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I'm shopping for a new Bluetooth headset for my iPhone 4 and noticed that some headsets support the apt-X codec for "CD-quality sound". Presumably this is better quality than plain old A2DP that I've been using so far.

Which iPhones (if any) support apt-X audio over Bluetooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No iPhone has native support for apt-X, but you can buy a dongle such as the [Sennheiser BTD 300i](http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/home_en.nsf/root/private_headphones_accessories#td_3_0) or a similar one from Creative to enable apt-X support.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no iPhones support aptX, but it is supported by the Mac OS X. You can use dongles from Creative, Sennheiser or Jaybird with the iPhone to take advantage of aptX audio quality.